# Table with columns of different sizes in two rows

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I was planning to use FOP to create a table structure like this:

```
|_Column1____2cm_|_Column2_2cm_|_Column3___3cm___|

|_Column4_2ndRow____3cm__|_Column5_2ndRow___4cm__|
```

As you may or may not see (depending on how this is displayed),
I'm trying to have two rows of columns with different widths: the first column in the first row is bigger than the column directly under it in the second row, so this is not a traditional table design but some kind of an "asymmetric" table.

I would like to ask you if this is achievable with FOP at all, and if so, if you have any tips on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It is achievable with FOP.

If you know HTML `<table>`, then FOP tables work very much the same.

In your case you create a 4 column, 2 row table, then use `colspan` to "merge" some of the cells.

```
┌───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│       │  colspan="2"  │       │
├───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│  colspan="2"  │  colspan="2"  │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘
```

In HTML, that would be:

```html
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 2cm">X</td>
    <td style="width: 2cm" colspan="2">X</td>
    <td style="width: 3cm">X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 3cm" colspan="2">X</td>
    <td style="width: 4cm" colspan="2">X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My XSL-FO is a bit rusty, but it should be something like:

```xml
<fo:table>
  <fo:table-column column-width="2cm"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="1cm"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="1cm"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="3cm"/>
  <fo:table-body>
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell><fo:block>X</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2"><fo:block>X</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell><fo:block>X</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2"><fo:block>X</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2"><fo:block>X</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

As you can see, very similar to the HTML.

Comment: Almost. `<fo:table-column column-width="2cm"/>`, etc. should be before the `fo:table-body` that should enclose the `fo:table-row`. The current `fo:table-column` should be `fo:table-cell` (with the occasional `number-columns-spanned`).

Comment: @TonyGraham Thanks for fixing my answer. I did say I was rusty. 

Comment: But the approach was correct, so it would have been petty to make another answer just to change the markup a little.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I'm sure i can take it from here, this is a perfect kickstart for me!
Very much appreciated!